# WooCommerce Sort-by SKU - Get numeric order correct

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, numeric

I have a website running WooCommerce and on the Product Category page we have the option "Sort by SKU in Ascending order". The products have SKUs in the format of 4 Alpha and 2 Numeric, e.g. BLHS-20.

The issue we have is when the list of products in the Product Category page is sorted the SKUs aren't in true numeric order.

Example:

BLHS-1
BLHS-10
BLHS-11
BLHS-2

What code would we need to get the SKUs to sort as follows?

BLHS-1
BLHS-2
BLHS-10
BLHS-11

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: _"we have the option **Sort by SKU..**"_. By default this is not present in WooCommerce. So please update your question with the way (code) how this filter is added, since an adjustment of that code will be necessary to arrive at an answer to your question. As new contributor, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) & [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we have a workaround. Because the SKU field is a text field the simple fix is to find the largest numeric part of the SKU and for all smaller numbers add leading zeros.

Example:

BLHS-01
BLHS-02
BLHS-10
BLHS-11

This sorts correctly.